# Way to hide splash screen?

Tags: splash-screen, hybrid-mobile-app, oracle-maf

Is it possible to hide splash screen in MAF app and directly display some form/page to gather information from user at place of splash screen, and while user is being entering his values then initial loading process (which loads behind splash screen) can be continue at back-end?

Answer (score -3):

The splash screen is of value to you as users know you app is loading.  Its purpose is to load quickly as the rest of the app sets up.

Why would you want to move logic into this visual process?  I want to caution you that I think it's a poor choice to reject industry standards.  Work with the framework.

Comment: Actually, Splash screens go against the official UI guidelines for both iOS and Android. Splash screens are an historical artifact of the desktop era. Everything should be done to minimize the loading of resources, even if that means keeping the user busy while the application is loading things in the background.